# Copying dynamic ranges into existing workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Complete beginner to VBA and having issues copying values between Workbooks.

My goal is to copy certain columns from a worksheet named SupExp and paste them in a different workbook with a worksheet named Expenses. The columns needed from SupExp are A:C, H:M, and O. The values I need start on row 9 for every column and any information above should be disregarded. The number of rows change every time this report comes in and this process needs to be done every time the worksheet SupExp comes in.

When pasted into Expenses the information needs to be pasted starting on the next empty row. So for instance if there is information in A100 of Expenses the values being copied from A9 of SupExp need to start on A101 of Expenses.

Columns A:C of SupExp match columns A:C of Expenses. Column O of SupExp needs to be placed in Column D of Expenses. Columns H:M of SupExp coincide with columns E:J.

Thank you for any help or recommendations on where to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are really beginning with VBA so, I will provide some overview information.

To do what you want, you should a VBA subroutine that can be called as a macro (from a button, keyboard shortcut etc.). There are tons of tutorials online to guide you through the basics of VBA programming, so I'll just skip to your specific problem.

To copy the contents of a cell or a range to somewhere else, you just need an attribution (`=`) involving the objects that represent the ranges and the desired properties (depending on whether you want to copy values, text, formulas etc.). The following example copies the values of cells A1-A5 on Sheet1 to cells B1-B5 on Sheet2:

```
Sub CopyData()
    WorkSheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B5").Value = WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value
End Sub
```

In your problem, you also will need to find the first empty cell in a column, to find out where you will write your data. One simple way to do this is to probe the contents of each cell in the column, checking if it is empty, until you find one that is. This example does just that with column A of the active sheet and the sets its value to a string, check it out:

```
Sub FirstEmpty()
    Dim aRow As Long
    aRow = 1
    While ActiveSheet.Range("A" & aRow).Value <> ""
        aRow = aRow + 1
    Wend
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & aRow).Value = "FOUND IT!"
End Sub
```

Notice that this will count as empty a cell that has a formula whose result is an empty string. If you want to avoid this, replace the `.Value` property in the `While` statement with the `.Formula` property. There are other (probably better) ways to reach the same result - I just wanted to present an option.

Try to combine these fragments and adapt to your problem. Experiment, google around... If you still can't solve your problem, post your code and ask for help again. Its easier to get help from the community if you already have some code and just need help to get it to work as expected. Good luck.